# How to reduce the machine's power consumption?

Tags: nvidia, power-management, 23.04

My machine, Thinkpad X1 extreme Gen 5 running Kubuntu 23.04 seems to have abnormally high power consumption, even in dile. The usual culprit, nvidia card, seems to be drawing 0% power and some unusual processes and wakeups seem to be at the top of the list.

Can someone please help me analyse my power consumption?
Here are the screenshots from powertop:

[image]
[image]

And the output of `top`. (Also confused with powertop saying 38% or something, with just 2% cpu load?)

[image]

Anyway, how should I reduce the power usage?

Comment: Why a downvote? It would help to know where I am going wrong in asking this question.

Comment: not the downvoter, but *please* post text as text, not as images.