# Lunar Lobster 23.04 battery problem

Tags: 23.04

I'm having a big problem after I updated to "Lunar Lobster 23.04", apparently the system is draining all my battery in a matter of minutes. But this happens only when the notebook is idle, is anyone else having this problem? any suggestion? I use a DELL G15 year 2022 with a CPU 12th Gen Intel i5-12500H (16) @ 4,500GHz and the GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile. When using version 22.04 LTS there was no problem in this regard. Regarding being idle, it usually has 1 browser tab and Visual Studio Code, nothing else.

Comment: I've not seen this with my machines, which are primarily Lenovos from 2015 ~ 2019. With a bit more detail, someone might be able to spot a pattern, though. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the brand/model/specs of your machine (2) what software the system is using while idle (browsers with 800 tabs, etc.) (3) how long the battery may have gone under 22.10 or another earlier version 

Comment: Pretty sure I saw a question to this effect yesterday, I'm looking for it now

Comment: maybe it was this one? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465029/how-to-reduce-the-machines-power-consumption

Comment: Pretty sure I saw a question where someone's battery drained in minutes and heated up as well in 23.04, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I edited the question with my technical specifications, for the moment I am turning off the notebook completely so that the system does not drain all the battery, two days ago I received a driver update mentioning the battery problem, I updated it in the expectation that it would solve the problem but without success.